# Post data from JavaScript to ApiController with POST method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm calling webservice from javascript code like this:

```
function callActionAjax(action, data) { //action is "sendnotification"
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    getWebServiceUrl().done(function (webServiceUrl) { //returns https://server/api
        var s = {
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            url: webServiceUrl + "/" + action,
            data: "foobar", //also tried: JSON.stringify(data)
            type: "POST"
            //tried contentType: "application/json"
        };
        jQuery.ajax(s).done(function () {
            deferred.resolve();
        }).fail(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

I also have MVC service, that receives the request. My controller looks like this:

```
public class SendNotificationController : ApiController
{
    public void PostSendNotification(dynamic data)
    {
        Console.Write("foo");
    }

    public string GetSendNotification()
    {
        return "Foo Bar.";
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint in PostSendNotification. I can see, that the method receives request, but the `data` is just empty object. When I tried adding `contentType` in JS side, the breakpoint would not be hit.

How to adjust my code? Eventually, I want to retrieve my `data` in Controller and be able to do something with it.

Comment: Try to change the parameter type to string instead of using dynamic and also in java-script  modify data: "foobar" to  data: {data : "foobar"},

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
    type: "POST"
```

to

```
    method: 'POST'
```

cheers